# Replacing a form text field with drop-down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I created a simple Tasks webapp using .NET 4.0 MVC & Entity Framework. Pulling data from a database.
I have tables:

```
Staff {PkId, FirstName, LastName}
Tasks {PkId, Task, TaskDescription, DueDate}
TasksAssigned {PkId, StaffId, TaskId}
```

When I go to Edit TasksAssigned record (Edit page) I'll get a form (stripped div/css for space)

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PkId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PkId)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StaffId)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskId)
```

But I need to be shown Task instead TaskId, and LastName instead StaffId. And I need is to have drop-downs in the form instead text field with all names and all tasks available so I can select other person or other task (or both).

I'm assuming I should use DropDownList() or DropDownListFor() ?

Thanks for any help.

**(addon)**
Let me try to explain better...
So, let's say there are Staff members:

```
{ 12, "John", "Dow" },
{ 15, "Bill", "Smith" }.
```

Let's say there is task

`{ 3, "Clean the printer", "Call company to clean the printer... ", "2016-06-25" }`.

So, there's going to be a record in TaskAssigned

```
{ 8, 12, 3 }
```

Ok?

Let's change the the record so the task is assigned to Bill instead John. So, I would click on *"Edit"* button and on the Edit page I would have form with two text fields ( [ and ] represent text field of the form)

> **Staff:** John Dow
>   **Task:** Clean the printer

To change it I have to replace the name with 15, Bill's ID, right? I would like to have a drop-down with names of John and Bill and then select Bill's name and when submit, Bill's ID will be stored in TasksAssigned table.

Comment: You question is too vague. Could you narrow down your question?

Comment: I know :(
I tried again on the bottom of the question (addon).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're including the other two tables when you call for your data. If so you should easily be able to display the fields you're needing with referencing towards the correct ones. Purely based on what's in your question this should look something like the below.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskId)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tasks.Task)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tasks.Task)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Staff.LastName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Staff.LastName)
```

I don't see the immediate need to show or even give an option to edit the PK value of the TaskAssigned entry. That's the reason I moved it to Hidden

If you want to give the users a dropdownlist you'll have to make sure you're sending the potential choices along in your Model. In this case you'll preferably want to be using a ViewModel to send along the choices.

That way you'll be able to do something like the below.

```
List<SelectListItem> listOfStaff = new List<SelectListItem>();
   listOfStaff.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "Mark",
          Value = "1"
        });
   listOfStaff.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "John",
            Value = "2",
            Selected = true
        });
```

Leading you to the DropDownListFor you already referenced in your question.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StaffId, model.listOfStaff, "-- Select Staffmember --")
```

Hope this helps you along a little more towards a working solution.

Comment: Hi Zephire,
Yes, all three tables are included and the code in your code-block is correct. It works and I'm happy to see that because I did the same. :-)
And, regarding the drop-down, I apologize if I ask stupid question - I'm a newbie in .NET, couldn't I use already included table Staff to show the list of the records?

Comment: Hi @Afan good to hear! You could generate the 'DropdownListFor' with unique names you already have in your resulting Model. However **take care** that when you'd be doing this you'll only have names that are already assigned to a task. Persons who never have been assigned to a task yet won't appear in the TasksAssigned table, hence the include will not include them in the Model you're working with. Suggestion to solve this is to make a ViewModel based on your TasksAssigned model, but include a List<SelectListItem> listOfStaff that you populate by grabbing all data from the Staff table.

Comment: Hi @Afan did you get this working on your side? If so please mark the answer as a solution. Thanks.